# Which language to use for automating clicks on a site whitout changing site code

Tags: javascript, html, automation, click

sorry if the question is not that clear. Basically I want to mimic a user input on a site without changing the code of the site. For example there is a button named "Button1" then I'd like to run a script that could for example Click(Button1).

I know next to nothing about this stuff and I've googled but the examples I find are always javascripts that are implemented in the site code which I don't want to do.

So, in which language could this be done, and with which command?

Comment: You can try iMacros http://imacros.net/overview

Comment: I tried imacros and it doesn't seems to work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to accomplish this just using JavaScript. There are two methods to send events from JavaScript `element.fireEvent` and `.element.dispatchEvent()`. Using a function to try both methods would look like:

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
    if (el.fireEvent) {
        el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
    } else {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
        evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
}
```

Then you could use `eventFire('button1','click')` and it would simulate the user clicking on button1. You can also use other event types to simulate more than just clicks.

You can then run this function as an external script or open your browsers console and type it into there then you can send the commands from there. Also Chrome has a snippets feature that allows you to run scripts from your browser on any page.

Comment: So, would this act as if the user pressed the button or just send http code to the server?

Comment: @Cpt. Pineapple It would act exactly the same as if the user pressed the button.

Comment: Then this should do what I need, I'm going to learn javascript now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to script the interaction with your site you can take a look at [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). It has plugins such as the [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) to simply record the interactions you want and reply them automatically.